# How to progress from here? (Uniform Cont.)

Tags: proof-verification, continuity, proof-writing, uniform-continuity

> Proving $\frac{x}{x-1}$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $(2,4)$.

By definition, $\lvert\frac{x}{x-1}- \frac{y}{y-1}\rvert< \epsilon$. As $4 >x,y > 2$ we can state: $\lvert\frac{x}{x-1} - \frac{y}{y-1}\rvert< \lvert\frac{x}{4-1} -\frac{ y}{4-1}\rvert < 1/3|x-y| < \epsilon/3$. Therefore $\delta = \min\{4,\epsilon/3\}.$

Is this the right approach? How do I prove uniform continuity on the upper bound $4$?

Any hints/help is appreciated.

Comment: You can show the function is continuous in $[2,4]$ and use Cantor's theorem.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: No...it seems problematic for (i) You shall pick $\epsilon$ first then show that there is a $\delta$ such that.... (ii) $x, y \in (2, 4)$ does not imply $ |x/(x -1) - y/(y - 1)| < |x - y|/3$. Take $x = 2.1, y = 2.4$, then the left hand side is 0.1948, the right hand side is 0.1.

Comment: Where should I start to prove this then? :S

Comment: See my answer. Let me have my dinner first:)

Comment: @PixelRain Note that I have to make some draft and compute $|x/(x - 1) - y /(y -1)|$ beforehand. Otherwise, I would never know taking $\delta = \epsilon$ would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick any $\epsilon > 0$. Take $\delta = \epsilon$. Pick any $x, y \in (2,4)$ such that $|x - y| < \delta$.

$$\bigg| \frac{x}{x -1} - \frac{y}{y-1}\bigg| =\bigg| \frac{x-y}{(x -1)(y -1)} \bigg| = \frac{|x - y|}{|x - 1||y -1|} < \frac{\delta}{|x - 1||y -1|} $$
But we have that $x - 1 > 1$ and $y -1> 1$. So that
$$\bigg| \frac{x}{x -1} - \frac{y}{y-1}\bigg| <  \frac{\delta}{|x - 1||y -1|}  < \delta. $$

Comment: if (x-1) > 1, why is that the inequality is < delta? Wouldn't the fraction with |x-1||y-1| > 1?

Comment: Then $|x -1|>1$ and taking reciprocal we get $1/|x -1| < 1$.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: @PixelRain It is a good exercise to prove that your function is (i) continuous in $(1, +\infty)$. (ii) NOT uniformly continuous on $(1, +\infty)$.

Comment: So I should just make up any function and show its continuous in that interval, but then prove by contradiction that it isn't uniformly cont?

Comment: You can make one but I meant that to be the function in your question :P

Comment: @Pixel Rain: Your function is continuous on $[\frac{3}{2},5]$, that is, it is uniformly continuous on this interval and all intervals contained in it.